# {CSS} hyphens:none; working in chrome and firefox but not safari (TRIED EVERYTHING)

Tags: css, safari, stylesheet, hyphenation

I am using a wordpress them that has awful support for word word wrapping, there is hyphenation and word breaks littered all over the site.

I have fixed the problem entirely on chrome and firefox but have tried a million things for safari but the problem persists.

This fixes chrome and firefox, and I believe it should fix Safari too right?

```
body, p,  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 -moz-hyphens: none !important;
-ms-hyphens: none !important;
-webkit-hyphens: none !important;
 hyphens: none !important;}
```

Comment: What version of safari are you having a problem with you can look at "can I use" and it will tell you browser support - https://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

Comment: This might be your best bet for working it out: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/ - It might be good if you could give a working example of your problem, maybe in something like jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am using Safari 12.1. so not an old version.

Comment: I can send you the live website if that helps?

Comment: also the css-tricks link, thats one of the many things I read, I've tried everything but safari is totally ignoring the command